How create truth table for ZFC axioms. What type of variables will be in the cells of this table?
My goal create truth table for ZFC axiom of extensionality:
$$ {\forall}a({\forall}b({\forall}c(((c{\in}a){\iff}(c{\in}b)){\iff}(a=b)))) $$
However, I come to this contradiction in my reasoning. To set values for these variables, I already have to know what the "set" is to fill the cells with them.
If the table cells do not contain sets but some mathematical objects, how can I enumerate them?



a
b
c
$$ {\forall}a({\forall}b({\forall}c(((c{\in}a){\iff}(c{\in}b)){\iff}(a=b)))) $$




?
?
?
0


?
?
?
1




Note that this axiom is not of the form $\forall a \forall b \forall c. P(a,b,c)$, so even if you'd restrict yourself to a finite set of possibilities for $a, b, c$, this is not going to work.

Truth-tables are completely inappropriate for this. Truth-tables are used in propositional logic, sometimes called sentential logic or truth-functional logic, which analyzes statements at the 'level' of whole sentences or propositions. That is, the 'atoms' of propositional logic are whole propositions, which are assumed to be true or false. Moreover the operators/connectives (=such as $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$, and $\to$) are assumed to be truth-functional, meaning that the truth-value of a complex sentence (like $A \land B$) is assumed to be a function of the truth-values of its parts.  And that is what a truth-table does: to show the truth-conditionals of a complex sentences in terms of the truth-values of its component parts.
However, once you move to predicate logic, or first-order logic, and start introducing objects, predicates, and quantifiers, then the analysis you do is no longer purely truth-functional: no longer can you say that the truth-value of a complex sentence is a function of the truth-values of its parts. Indeed, the 'parts' in that ZFC Axiom of Extensionality are things like $a$ and $\in$, which are not propositions, and thus have no truth-value at all, so it makes no sense to have $a$ as a line in a traditional truth-table.
Now, a somewhat different way to look at a truth-table is to see them as a way to exhaustively explore all possible kinds of worlds. So, given that you are working with sets, you could try to exhaust all possibilities of assigning sets to $a$, $b$, and $c$ .. this is in fact what it seems like you are trying to do.  But there is an obvious problem here: there are infinitely many sets. In fact, there are uncountably many!  So even if you use a table as a 'explore all possibilities' kind of method, this is just not feasible given your domain.

Thank you for the answer. From your answer I got a statement - "a formula of first-order logic sometimes (always?) cannot be represented by a truth table" . I would like to understand this topic in detail. Could you recommend a book or a chapter in a book that I could read to understand this?
From the third paragraph I understand "possibilities of assigning sets to " .Why do we assign "sets"?  Because the concept of set is not defined yet.  Maybe by set we mean naive set theory or something else?

@J.Doe Basically any decent book on introductory formal logic should help with this: if you look at the part of the book that deals with propositional logic you'll see truth-tables .. once you move to predicate/quantificational/first-order logic, those tables disappear. They don't always explain why, but I tried to explain in my Answer

@J.Doe Maybe this helps:  the statement $\forall x \ P(x)$ clearly has different truth-conditions from $\exists x \ P(x)$=. But a truth-functional analysis just isn't possible to show that: there are no smaller parts that can still be assigned a truth-value:  $P(x)$ is not a statement, and has no truth-value, and so the truth-value of $\forall x \ P(x)$ is not a function of the truth-value of any smaller statements .. there simply are no smaller statements.

@J.Doe Also, I did say that you could possibly go through all possible sets to see if the Extensionality Axiom holds ... though that is already assuming the domain is sets. Pure logic doesn't specify any domain, and variables and predicates can be interpreted in any which way. Maybe the domain is all people in the world, $\in$ stands for 'larger than', in which case your axiom is saying: If c is a person larger than both persons $a$ and $b$, then $a$ and $b$ are the same person ... which ends up being a false statement of course.

@J.Doe So you couldn;t even constrain yourself to sets if you want to analyze the truth-conditions of this Axiom:L you'd have to consider all possible domains .. of which there are uncountably many.

I think I need to better learn to understand these issues, so if I figure it out, I’ll come to this topic maybe in a month (if I can figure it out). But before that I would like to clarify. Isn't the formula ∀x P(x) not equal P(x1) ∧  P(x2)  ∧  P(x3) ...? if so then why can't  ∀x P(x)  formula be truth functional with smaller parts : P(x1),P(x2)...

@J.Doe The issue is still that you need to consider all possible worlds, and in first-order logic the truth-value of a statement can depend on how many objects there are in the domain. Thus, for example, a statement could be true in a world with at most 3 objects .. or in a world with at least 17 .. or in a world with exactly 6537 objects. And note that in a world with 2 objects, $\forall x \ P(x)$ will come to mean $P(c_1) \land P(c_2)$, but in a world with 3 objects it will be $P(c_1) \land P(c_2) \land P(c_3)$, and in other worlds it will be different yet.

Also, domains with infinitely many sets you would get an infinitely long statement like that ... which in classical logic isn't even allowed. And if there are uncountably many objects (e.g. the real numbers ... and also the domain of 'all sets'), you can't even capture with an infinite formula like $P(c_1) \land P(c_2) \land ...$!

And even if you focus on a single kind of world with, say, $n$ objects, note that you would need to consider $2^n$ rows in a truth-table, just for that world, and that's if we're just dealing with a single 1-place predicate. In this case we are dealing with a 2-place predicate $\in$, so now you need to consider $2^{n^2}$ rows!! And that's just for 1 of the uncountable many different worlds you would need to consider.  It is just not possible to do all of them, even if you restrict yourself to just the finite ones. And even if you consider a finite number of worlds, it is still wayyy too much

Thanks for the information! I'll think about it.
